# Visual issue using Frambuffer Object as texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fbo, render-to-texture

My OpenGL engine draws a given scene into a Framebuffer Object, then uses its color attachment as a texture. It is then put on a square in the viewport.

The problem is that I see a strange visual artifact:

[image]

The square is built with

```
glm::vec2 square[4];
square[0] = glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f);
square[1] = glm::vec2(engWidth, 0.f);
square[2] = glm::vec2(0.f, engHeight);
square[3] = glm::vec2(engWidth, engHeight);
glm::vec2 texcoords[4];
texcoords[0] = glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f);
texcoords[1] = glm::vec2(1.f, 0.f);
texcoords[2] = glm::vec2(0.f, 1.f);
texcoords[3] = glm::vec2(1.f, 1.f);

glGenBuffers(2, Buffer2D);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer2D[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(glm::vec2), square, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer2D[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(glm::vec2), texcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

orthographicProj = glm::ortho(0.f, (float)engWidth, 0.f, (float)engHeight, -1.f, 1.f);
```

Where engWidth and engHeight are the actual window size.

Then the frame is rendered with

```
shaderProgram->setMatrix("Clip", orthographicProj);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer2D[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer2D[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Vertex and fragment shaders for the final phase are simple

```
const char *frontVertexShader = R"(
    #version 440 core

    uniform mat4 Clip;

    layout(location = 0) in vec2 Position;
    layout(location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;

    out vec2 Tex_Coord;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = Clip * vec4(Position, 0.0, 1.0);
        Tex_Coord = TexCoord;
    }
)";

const char *frontFragmentShader = R"(
    #version 440 core

    in vec2 Tex_Coord;  
    uniform sampler2D sampler;

    out vec4 Fragment;

    void main() {
        Fragment = texture(sampler, Tex_Coord);
    }
)";
```

I tried using triangles instead a triangle strip but with the same result.

Any idea? I can post more code if needed.

Comment: Just curious as to why you have a clip matrix there.  What's it used for?  If the geometry you send in is normalised -1 to 1, you just pass it through and the texture coordinate is * 0.5 and add 0.5 to the vertex position and you're done.

Comment: First of all, have you verified that your texture contents are acutally corrent, i.e. the artifact is not already in the texture? Apart from that: Make sure your fragments are not discarded (depth test, stencil test etc.).

Comment: Actually I didn't, but it should since the rendering in the FBO is done in the same way it was in the backbuffer. Anyway I will save the content to an image to check that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help, but for what it's worth this is what I do for a full screen quad:

(Note the vertex has no texture component - it's just -1 to 1).

```
v[0].x = -1.f; v[0].y = -1.f; v[0].z = 0.f;
v[1].x = -1.f; v[1].y =  1.f; v[1].z = 0.f;
v[2].x =  1.f; v[2].y = -1.f; v[2].z = 0.f;
v[3].x =  1.f; v[3].y =  1.f; v[3].z = 0.f;
```

The vertex shader is simply:

```
void main()
{
    attrib_Fragment_Texture = attrib_Position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5; 

    gl_Position = vec4(attrib_Position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

With the following pixel shader:

```
void main(void)
{
    Out_Colour = texture2D(Map_Diffuse, attrib_Fragment_Texture);
}
```

You don't need an orthographic projection matrix.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could avoid using the orthographic matrix. I used this code and now it looks cleaner. However, the issue it's still there.

Comment: Ah ok.  It does look odd.  I thought at first it might be a sampling issue but the edge is too rough.

Comment: You don't even need to use vertex attributes to do this in a GLSL 4.40 shader. Just use `const vec4 pos [4] = vec4 [] (vec4 (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4 (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4 (1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4 (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)); gl_Position = pos [gl_VertexID]; attrib_Fragment_Texture = pos [gl_VertexID].xy * 0.5 + 0.5;` No vertex buffers need to be allocated or bound, and it should work a little quicker.

Comment: Haha nice.  Thanks for that Andon.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! I forgot to call glClear on the backbuffer and for a strange reason only some pixel presented the issue.